# a4j:jsFunction with actionListener inside of h:dataTable

Tags: javascript, jsf, datatable

I'm having problem with using a4j:jsFunction with actionListener inside of h:dataTable, when I want to invoke an action over particular row with a4j:commandLink it works flawless but when I want to invoke the action with a4j:jsFunction & actionListener it's always invoked over the last element in dataTable
Let me give you an example:

```
    <a4j:form ajaxSubmit="true" reRender="mainForm" id="mainForm">
        <a4j:region>
            <t:saveState value="#{ts.list}" />
        </a4j:region>

        <h:dataTable value="#{ts.list}" var="el" binding="#{ts.bind}">
        <h:column>#{el}</h:column>>
        <h:column>
            <a4j:commandLink actionListener="#{ts.rem}">
                    <h:outputText value="delete by CMDLink" />
                </a4j:commandLink>
            </h:column>
        <h:column>
                <a href="#" onclick="okClicked();">delete by okClicked</a>
                <a4j:jsFunction name="okClicked"
                    actionListener="#{ts.rem}"
                />
        </h:column>
   </h:dataTable>
    </a4j:form>
```

now, the bean's code:

```
package com.sth;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.component.UIData;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

public class Ts {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private UIData bind;

    public Ts(){
        list.add("element1");
        list.add("element2");
        list.add("element3");
        list.add("element4");
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void rem(ActionEvent ae) {
        String toRem = (String) bind.getRowData();
        System.out.println("Deleting " + toRem);
        list.remove(toRem);
    }

    public UIData getBind() {
        return bind;
    }

    public void setBind(UIData bind) {
        this.bind = bind;
    }

}
```

when I use a4j:commandLink to remove element, it works as its expected, but when I use a4j:jsFunction to invoke actionListener it invokes action against last element :(
Any ideas?
Cheers

Comment: What's the reason to prefer `a4j:jsFunction` above `a4j:commandLink` at any way?

Comment: I want to do "modal confirm box" with jQuery so jQuery dialog will fire okClicked() from jsFunction

Answer (score 1):

you can achive your goal by moving **<a4j:jsFunction>** out from **<h:datatable>** control

This is an example

```
 <a4j:form ajaxSubmit="true" reRender="mainForm" id="mainForm">

    <h:dataTable value="#{ts.list}" var="el" binding="#{ts.bind}">
      <h:column>#{el}</h:column>>
      <h:column>
            <a4j:commandButton 
                onclick="#{rich:component
                     ('confirmation')}.show();return false">Delete</a4j:commandButton>
      </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="remove" action="#{ts.remove(el)}" reRender="mainForm"/>
 </a4j:form>
```

Confirmation dialog:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="confirmation" width="250" height="150">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:graphicImage value="/img/delete.gif"/>
                <h:outputText value="Confirmation"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid style="height: 100%">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5px">
                <h:graphicImage value="/img/error_large.gif"/>
                <h:outputText value="Delete ?" style="font-size: large;"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGroup style="margin-top: 20px">
                <input type="button" value="Yes" style="width: 100px"
                       onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide();remove();return false"/>
                <input type="button" value="No" style="width: 100px"
                       onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide();return false"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </rich:modalPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments it turns out that you just want to fire a confirmation dialogue. You can also use `a4j:commandLink` for this, call it in the `onclick` attribute and let it return either true or false to either allow or block the action. Here's a kickoff example as you would do with a standard confirmation dialog:

```
<a4j:commandLink onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
```

This way you don't need to struggle/debug the weird `a4j:jsFunction` behaviour for hours.

Comment: Thank you BalusC for response :-)
I have already used this solution, I wanted to engage jQuery dialog to have sth 'eye friendly' but it seems there is no easy solution for that

Comment: Yes, I know. It was just a kickoff example. Replace `confirm()` by your jQuery function. The whole point is to let it return either true or false to block the default link action.

Comment: unfortunately jQuery dialog is not working in this way, I was fighting with the same problem some weeks ago:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812500/jquery-jsf-and-a4jcommandlink

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that with the a4j:jsFunction tag:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="okClicked" actionListener="#{ts.rem}" />
```

being placed within a column of a datatable, a JavaScript function called `okClicked` would be added to the HTML page in the column for each row of the table. Having the same name, each JavaScript function would overwrite the definition of the previous one, so that when `okClicked()` is called, only the last defined function is actually executed. This would be why the `actionListener` is being invoked that invokes the "action against last element".

A way around this would be to include the row index as part of the name of the JavaScript function being created by the a4j:jsFunction tag:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{ts.list}" var="el" binding="#{ts.bind}" rowIndexVar="index">
    <h:column>
        <a href="#" onclick="okClicked#{index}();">delete by okClicked</a>
        <a4j:jsFunction name="okClicked#{index}" actionListener="#{ts.rem}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:datatable>
```

I've not tested the above solution (and I don't know whether there would be an issue binding `#{ts.rem}` to a JS function `actionListener` rather than binding it to a `commandLink` `actionListener`) but if the `onClick` value of `okClicked#{index}();` doesn't work directly, then instead call a javaScript function that creates the function name from a string built from the index value:

```
function onClicked(row) {
    functionStr = "okClicked" + row;
    window[functionStr]();
}
```

I've had to use something similar requiring a grid of 'jsFunction's within a datatable where I had multiple columns to deal with as well as multiple rows.

Hope this is useful for others in the future.